# Is there a config option to add a field for link text in Ckeditor Link dialog?

Tags: ckeditor

I know that in order to make a link in Ckeditor you type in the text and then highlight it and then click the Link button and add the URL and then press OK. Problem is that many of our customers are used to having it also to be able to add the link text, name or description whatever you want to call it in the Link dialog. So is there a way to add that field? We are using Ckeditor version 4.5.6.

I would like to have something like this:

[image]

But currently it's like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Currently that feature is not available. There's a feature request for that, but you can't be sure when it will be available.

You can use the API instead to modify the link dialog on the fly and add that field.

Comment: Ok I was afraid of that but thank you for your answer. I shall look into the API how to add it if the feature has not been published in the near future. This is not a show stopper for us. It is just that many users are used to having that field from the old Sceditor that we used to have. Sceditor project died so we moved to using Ckeditor.